# Why does Midnight Commander look crap in SSH clients?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-10.04

Why does MC look like [this](http://yfrog.com/jdcrapuij) in SSH clients (I've tried PuTTY and MindTerm) and how to fix it?

On the server side is fresh installed 64-bit Ubuntu 10.04 Server. On the client side is XP SP3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the exact answer [here](http://www.andremiller.net/content/getting-midnight-commander-line-drawing-work-putty):

> After some experimentation it turns out that to fix it all you have to do is change your character set in PuTTY to UTF-8 and the problem is fixed. To do this open up the PuTTY settings and go to Window->Translation->Received data assumed to be in which character set: and change it to UTF-8.

Answer (score 3):

This has been addressed (putty specifically) on superuser:
https://superuser.com/questions/75088/putty-correct-translation-on-ubuntu-8-04

Answer (score -3):

It's a character set mismatch. Why don't you just use WinSCP?

Comment: WinSCP (a pure SCP/SFTP client) and PuTTY (a full-featured SSH client) do quite different things, although the underlying protocol is the same.

Comment: @joschi, I'm well aware they do different things, as I use them both every day. I was suggesting WinSCP as an alternative to MC, not PuTTY. I'd have thought that was obvious from the context.

Comment: John, Midnight Commander and WinSCP also have vastly different use cases and are usually not interchangeable.

Comment: To those who feel an urge to downvote this answer I can only say that you have clearly not discovered just how effective a file manager WinSCP really is.